# show current item in custom menu, when inside a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I have a custom post type "product". I need to have its index accessible from the main menu, so i 've added a Custom Menu entry, simply stating "/works/" as url value. Problem is: if i'm looking at a single product, the main index menu link does not receive the current_menu_ancestor class. Any idea how to fix that?

```
register_post_type( 'product',      
                array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Works' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Work' ),
                'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Work'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Work'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Work'),
                'new_item' => __('New Work'),
                'view_item' => __('View Work'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Works'),
                'not_found' =>  __('No Work found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Work found in Trash'), 
                'menu_name' => 'Works'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search'=>false,
            'show_ui '=>true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_menu '=>true,
            'show_in_nav_menus '=>true,
            'has_archive' => 'works',
            'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'work','with_front'=>false),
            'menu_position' => 2,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png',
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports'=>array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt'),
            'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag')
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your functions.php:

```
function additional_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){
    global $wp_query;

    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $menu_item->classes)){
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    if ( $menu_item->post_name == 'product' && is_post_type_archive('product') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    if ( $menu_item->post_name == 'product' && is_singular('product') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }


    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'additional_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```

This code check if you are on a page product archive or an single product and if so it adds the class current-menu-item

Comment: Right now it doesn't seem to work, but i'll play with it. I'm not sure i need to check against `$menu_item->post_name`. Thank you.